# Trouble with Properties in SolutionToBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying to use the Properties Metadata in the SolutionToBuild item in Team Build.

I am adding the version to the Properties  metadata inside a target that gets called before the code is even gotten (BuildNumberOverrideTarget), but I guess that is too late.  My changed values do not get passed to solutions that are built.

When does this data get passed to the solutions (clearly before they are pulled from source control).

If I want to do some calculations (ie version number) before this happens is there a target that this can be done in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should help you out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/05/12/orcas-sp1-tfs-build-changes-part-2.aspx

If you add your dynamically generated property to the CustomPropertiesForBuild it will be available later in your build process.